# Why does an argument similiar to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...=1$ show that $2+4+8+...=-2$

Tags: real-numbers

See how to prove $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...=1$

$x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...$

$2x=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...$

Then:

$x=1$

Now I use the same argument to prove $2+4+8+...=-2$

$x=2+4+8+...$

$2x=4+8+16+...$

Then:

$x=-2$

Comment: The series you are writing down to represent $x$ does not converge, and subtracting divergent series (particularly, $\infty - \infty$) is in general undefined.

Comment: The argument shows that *if* you have a way of making sense of the sum, and if that way satisfies certain basic properties, then the sum would have to be $-2$.  But the value is conditional on you having a way of making sense of the sum.  In the standard approach to sums of real numbers, the sum is just divergent, and your first line "$x=\ldots$" is just wrong.  In fact, if you are in a framework where a sum of positive numbers must be positive, this is a proof by contradiction that the sum cannot exist.

Comment: An infinite sum (aka a series) only has a value, if it converges. To decide whether a series converges you need to specify a metric. The tag *real numbers* tells me that you think of this as series of real numbers with metric determined by the usual absolute value. In that case the answer is simply that this series diverges, and has no value. Therefore the process of trying to determine a value is not on solid footing (basically because many steps ASSUME that the series has a value). However, if you use the 2-adic metric, then the scene becomes markedly different (see Achille Hui's post).

Comment: (cont'd) Because awareness of the dependence of the convergence on the choice of metric, and the existence of metrics (on the set of rational numbers) other than the usual absolute value require a level of mathematical sophistication that a typical asker here does not possess, I'm inclined to reclose this as duplicate. However, apparently regular users disagree on the best course of action.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: I voted to reopen when the close was due to lack of context - which IMHO applies to PSQ posts, not to posts about points of mathematical confusion (and this has at least some minimal context). If this is viewed as duplicate, then closing it for that reason would be OK with me. It is true that the 0.999 question is similar, but it has the separate well known confusion/problem that some students don't recognize 0.999... as a series in the first place. At least this question is explicitly about a series; I didn't see immediately from the title that is was a duplicate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I actually can't vote to close as duplicate again, my vote to close was part of the five who first closed the question... (only three users had voted as "no context", the other two as duplicate) Well, we'll see what happens.

Comment: "but when I show this proof they have nothing to say." Is that so? I find this surprising.

Comment: why it isn't duplicated.

Comment: $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^k = 0$$

Comment: @CountIblis Losing the OP still a little more?

Comment: @CarlMummert He probably doesn't know that 0.99999... is a series.

Answer (score 12):

In the proof, you have begun by implicitly saying "Assume that the sequence converges, and call the limit $x$". For $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots$, you obtain $x = 1$. For $2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots$, you obtain $x = -2$.

But that means you have only proved "If $2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots$ converges, then it converges to $-2$". This does not show that the series $2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots$ actually converges. That has to be established separately.

In the case of $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots$, you can prove by induction that the partial sums are bounded by $1$, and then use the monotone convergence theorem to prove that the series converges. Until you prove the series converges, you don't actually know from your previous calculation that the limit of $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots$ *is* $1$. You only know that *if* $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + \cdots$ converges, then the limit is $1$.

Now, you can't prove the series $2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots$ converges, because it doesn't. But you can prove that if it did converge the limit would be $-2$ - which is still consistent with the series not converging.  This is all that your calculation shows.

So the method you are using is fine, but you have to remember that it is relatively meaningless to try to compute the value of a series if the series doesn't converge. When you use the method in the question to compute the value of a series, you have to prove separately that the series converges.

Answer (score 7):

$\def\bR{\mathbb{R}}\def\bQ{\mathbb{Q}}$Well, $\sum_{k\geq1} 2^k$ converges to $-2$, but not in $\bR$, it does so in $\bQ_2$, the [$2$-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) completion of $\bQ$. (In $\bR$, it obviously diverges.)

Let me prove that $\sum_{k\geq0} 2^k\to-1$, which is the same (just multiply by $2$). We have, for the partial sums, $A_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k= 2^n-1$ and then $A_n-(-1)=2^n$ and $2^n\to0$ in the $2$-adic sense.

So what you discovered is that series that are divergent in $\bR$ need not be divergent in other completions of $\bQ$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint the series converges only if $|r|<1$ so your second proof is wrong as $|r|=2$

Answer (score 4):

The proof does work if you interpret it correctly.

In the proof for $\frac12 + \frac14 + \cdots = 1$, you are using the fact in
$\mathbb{R}$, the successive term $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is getting smaller and smaller as $n$ getting bigger and bigger.
The partial sums
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{\frac12 - \frac{1}{2^{N+1}}}{1 - \frac12} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^N}$$
getting closer and closer to $1$ as $N$ increases. This means in $\mathbb{R}$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n}
\text{ exists and equal to } 1$$

If you look at the other sum $2 + 4 + \cdots$, the successive term $2^n$ doesn't getting smaller and smaller as $n$ increases. The corresponding partial sums doesn't converge. In order for your argument to work, a prerequisite is the partial sum converges. When the partial sums fail to converge, the difference of two indeterminates is an indeterminate. Your argument will fail
and you cannot conclude $2 + 4 + \cdots = -2$ when working within $\mathbb{R}$.

However, there is more than one way to extend $\mathbb{Q}$. For each prime number $p$, there is a beast $\mathbb{Q}_p$ called [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). In particular, for
$p = 2$, the successive terms $2^n$ does getting smaller and smaller as $n$ increases. If you work within the $2$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_2$, you argument will work and the series does converge to $-2$ there.

Answer (score 3):

You can't subtract divergent series.

Comment: Why not? These "fastest gun in the west"-type answers are getting tiring.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: If you are the person who downvoted it, then you're misusing the downvoting system. As far as answering OP's question matters, this is a perfectly correct answer.

Comment: The hover-text for the downvote arrow says "This answer is not useful". I don't think this answer is useful, hence a downvote :) Compare your answer with e.g. Carl Mummert's answer.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Then your definition of useful is flawed.This is a useful answer because it answers OP's question and tells him why what he has written is not a paradox in mathematics. + I don't think talking about $p$-adic numbers to someone who still doesn't fully understand basic laws of calculus is "useful", if not harmful.

Comment: When they write $x = $, they are making an implicit assumption that the series converges, and of course it is OK to subtract convergent series.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The answer is quite simple: It is simply not well-defined

Comment: how do you know it is infinity

Comment: @TahaAkbari: Look at the partial sums, $s_n$. $2^n \leq s_n$ for any $n$. Now let $n$ go to infinity.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: I just read your profile and noticed that you're in 8th grade. What definition of infinity do you know?

Comment: @TahaAkbari when you write $x = something$ for a series, you mean that the limit that the series is approaching is $something$. It means that you can add as many terms as you want but you will never exceed that limit. $$S = {a(r^n -1)\over (r-1)}$$. Now in a convergent series $r = 1/w$, $$S = {a(1/w^n -1)\over (1/w-1)}$$ , now limit both sides with $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, You will see that $1/w^n \to 0$, thus $$S = {a\over (1-1/w)}$$ $$=S = {a\over (1-r)}$$. Now do the same for a divergent series and you will see that $r^n = w^n$, which is unbounded. thus the sum, $S$ is unbounded (infinite).

Comment: @TahaAkbari I will assume that you don't calculus. So my advice, if you do what you did here when learning calculus then you would be in great trouble like me. Never treat $\infty$ as a number because it is not, you can't do $\infty- \infty = 0$. Consider this $w = \infty + 1$, which is same as $w  = \infty$ now $w - \infty = \infty + 1 - \infty \Rightarrow 0 = 1$, which of course incorrect.